# Does background playback still work with cordova media plugin on iOS 10?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, background-process, cordova-media-plugin

I'm trying to get an audio sample to play in an Ionic/Cordova App when a bluetooth device goes out of range and the iOS device is either in standby (screen locked) or the App is minimised to the background.

I'm using a similar function to the example in the [Cordova media plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media), with a function to correct the audio file path for Android devices:

```
function getMediaURL(url) {
    if(device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") return "/android_asset/www/" + url;
    return url;
};

function soundAlarm() {
    var mediaUrl = getMediaURL('sounds/alarm.wav');

    alarmSound = new Media( mediaUrl, null,
    // error callback
    function (err) {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + angular.toJson(err));
    });

    alarmSound.play({ playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : true, numberOfLoops: 3 });
}
```

This works fine when the App is in the foreground however when I lock the phone or minimise the App I get the following error:

```
{"message":"","code":4}
```

According to the [Cordova media plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media), error code 4 means

> MEDIA_ERR_NONE_SUPPORTED

The 'playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked' option I pass into the play method is supposed to handle the issue I'm having however I just get the above error every time. Besides, this property is set to true by default.

I don't want to have to use a background mode plugin as this functionality should work out of the box via cordova media plugin and the background mode plugin may cause the App to be rejected from the App Store.

Has anyone had any success triggering audio while the App is in the background or the device is in standby mode?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I'm facing the same issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to enable 'Background Modes' and check 'Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture' from Xcode to get it to work.

Comment: Where did you find the 'Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture' option? I had to use the background-mode plugin and only temporarily enabled it to allow the sound to play. I was able to do it this way because my App is partially awoken by an event from a bluetooth device which interacts with the App, however the App did not seem to awake enough to play the sound without the aid of the background-mode plugin.

[I submitted a bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12422) but all that came of it was an addition to the documentation.

Comment: It's in XCode, click on your project file in the Project Navigator.  In the main pane you should now see "General", "Capabilities", etc etc going across the top. Click "Capabilities" and then enable and expand "Background Modes".

If this works for you please accept the answer for future visitors. :)